# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult VerifyUserEmail(string User_Email)
{
  try
  {
    using (EmptyMVCApplicationEntities objConnection = new EmptyMVCApplicationEntities())
    {
      ObjectParameter objIErrorCode = new ObjectParameter("ErrorCode", typeof(Int32));  
      ObjectParameter objBFlag = new ObjectParameter("bFlg", typeof(bool));
      objConnection.Check_User_Exists(User_Email, objBFlag, objIErrorCode);
      if (Convert.ToBoolean(objBFlag.Value) != true)
      {
        return Json(new { Success = "false", Message = "Email exists" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }
      else
      {
        return Json(new { Success = "True", Message = "Email not exists" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      }               
    }
  }
  catch (Exception Ex) 
  {    
  }
}
```

Script

```
$("#User_Email").blur(function () {
  if ($(this).val() != "") {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/User/VerifyUserEmail?User_Email=" + $("#User_Email").val(),
      success: function (result) {
        try {
          var jsonIssueObj = $.parseJSON(result).Data;    
        }  catch (e) { alert(e); }
        if (!jsonIssueObj.Success) {
          var errorMsg = jsonIssueObj.Message;
          $('#msg').html(errorMsg);
          $('#msg').show();
        }
        else {
          var errorMsg = null;
          $('#msg').html(errorMsg);
          $('#msg').hide();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

I am getting below error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Also If I want Success and Message in an object, how to pass an object as json in controller actionresult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You returning json with 2 properties, `Success` and `Message` (you do not need `parseJSON`). To access them

```
success: function (result) {
  var success = result.Success;
  var message = result.Message;
  ....
```

Comment: Thanks Stepphen Muecke. It works. How to pass this two property in a single object?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by _How to pass this two property in a single object?_ It **is** a single object (with 2 properties)