# JSON.parse() not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a json from my server which is -

```
{"canApprove": true,"hasDisplayed": false}
```

I can parse the json like this -

```
var msg = JSON.parse('{"canApprove": true,"hasDisplayed": false}');
alert(msg.canApprove);  //shows true.
```

At my ajax response function I caught the same json mentioned earlier by a method parameter `jsonObject` -

```
//response function
function(jsonObject){

  //here jsonObject contains the same json -  {"canApprove":true,"hasDisplayed": false}
  //But without the surrounding single quote
  //I have confirmed about this by seeing my server side log.

  var msg = JSON.parse(jsonObject); // this gives the error

}
```

But now I got the following error -

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of
>   the JSON data

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the error?

Comment: console.log(jsonObject) display what?

Comment: That almost certainly means that the JSON has already been parsed. Add `console.log(typeof jsonObject);` to your response function right before you try to parse it. I bet it's "Object".

Comment: Please read the full question, he is trying to parse the json string and not an already parsed json. It's in his code comments.

Comment: @Pointy The ajax call back send string all the time, no?

Comment: @R3tep yes, but depending on exactly how the ajax call is being made, some software on the client may automatically parse it. That's true for example when you do an ajax request via jQuery and tell it that the response type is JSON.

Comment: @taxicala this question comes up all the time. That's exactly the error you get if you pass the `.toString()` output from an already-parsed object into `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Pointy Or if the call back value is empty. Like : `JSON.parse(" ");`

Comment: @R3tep yes that would do it too!  The important thing is for the OP to come back to the question and tell us what the `console.log()` call shows.

Comment: console.log(typeof jsonObject) --> object and console.log(jsonObject) --> [object object]

Comment: @Razib: Well, there you go, `jsonObject` is already an object. `JSON.parse` expects a **string** containing JSON.

Comment: [Likely duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28271418/syntaxerror-json-parse-unexpected-character-at-line-1-column-2-of-the-json-dat)

Comment: @pointy yes , you were right at least in my case. The  JSON was already parsed. I simply used result.message instead of var msg = JSON.parse(jsonObject);

Comment: Not the same error but I solved my issue using `$.parseJSON` where `JSON.parse` was not working and throwing an error *`JSON.parse is not a function`*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I dont think you should call `JSON.parse(jsonObject)` if the server is sending valid JSON as it will be parsed automatically when it retrieves the response. I believe that if You set the `Content-type: application/json` header it will be parsed automatically.

Try using `jsonObject` as if it was already parsed, something like:

```
console.log(jsonObject.canApprove);
```

Without calling `JSON.parse` before.

Comment: Note that having valid JSON and setting `Content-type: application/json` are two different things. Having valid JSON usually does not imply automatic parsing.

Comment: @taxicala I noticed that if you use `dataType:"json"` on the ajax() jQuery method, you don´t need to use parse() (you actually get the error told by the OP if you do); but you must use it if you don´t  specify `dataType:"json"`. I must investigate why is that. Any clue?

Comment: I guess you should use replace function before JSON.parse 
example : 
var data = "{\"name\":\"alan\",\"age\":34}"
 str = data.replace(/\\/g, ''); 
// then use JSON.pase function 
var jsonObj =JSON.parse(str);

Answer (score 31):

Your JsonObject seems is a Json Object. The reasons why you can't parse Json from a String:

- the String is surround by `" "`. and use `\"` escape inside. Here is an example:

  `"{\"name\":\"alan\",\"age\":34}"`

  when you try to parse above string by `JSON.parse()`, still return the a string:`{"name":"alan","age":34}`, and  `\"` is replace by `"`. But use the `JSON.parse()` function again, it will return the object you want. So in this case,you can do this:

  `JSON.parse(JSON.parse("{\"name\":\"alan\",\"age\":34}" ))`
- Your string use `'` instead of  `"` . example:

  `{'name':'alan','age':34}`

  if you try to parse above string by `JSON.parse()`, may cause error

Comment: I guess you should use replace function  before JSON.parse

example : 

 var data = "{\"name\":\"alan\",\"age\":34}"
          str = data.replace(/\\/g, '');
// then use JSON.pase function
   
var jsonObj =JSON.parse(str);

Answer (score 7):

This answer might help someone who's storing JSON as a string in SQL databse.

I was storing the value of following

```
JSON.stringify({hi:hello})
```

in MySQL. The JSON stored in SQL was `{"hi":"hello"}`

Problem was when I read this value from db and fed it to `JSON.parse()` it gave me error.

I tried wrapping it in quotes but didn't work.

Finally following worked

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonFromDb))
```

This worked and JSON was parsed correctly.

I know the storing mechanisim might not be appropriate however those were client needs.

Answer (score 4):

Its already an object, no need to parse it. Simply try

```
alert(jsonObject.canApprove)
```

in your response function.

Json.parse is expecting a string.

Comment: *"Its already valid Json, no need to parse it."* JSON always has to be parsed. Maybe you mean "it's an object"?

Answer (score 2):

Your `jsonObject` seems already parsed, you need to test if this is the case.

```
function(jsonObject){
    var msg = (typeof jsonObject == "object" ? jsonObject : JSON.parse(jsonObject));
}
```

It's also possible that your call back is empty, it's generates the same error if you try to parse an empty string. So test the call back value.

```
function(jsonObject){
    if(jsonObject) {
       var msg = (typeof jsonObject == "object" ? jsonObject : JSON.parse(jsonObject));
    }
}
```

Comment: *"If you send a valid JSON, you don't need to parse it"* That is not true in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
var text = '{"canApprove": true,"hasDisplayed": false}';

var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(text);

alert(parsedJSON.canApprove);
```

This works. It is possible that you use `"` instead of `'` while creating a String.

Comment: But I have `jsonObject`. How can I convert it to `text`?

Comment: @Razib: I thought you wanted to *parse* JSON into an object. Do you want to go the other way round now? Why?

Comment: Why don't you use jsonObject.toString() and then send it to JSON.parse

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to make an ajax call and parse the result:

```
var query = {
    sUserIds: JSON.stringify(userIds),
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: your-url,
    data: JSON.stringify(query),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
        var your_object = JSON.parse(response.d);
    }, 
    failure: function (msg) {
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function (a, b, c) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and now it's solved. I'm using ASP.Net MVC to send value to .js file. The problem was that I was returning JsonResult from the Action method, because of this JSON.parse was failing in .js file. I changed the return type of Action method to string, now JSON.parse is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

As someone mentioned up there, this actually fixes the problem. What I learnt from this is that may be how PHP encodes a json object is not familiar to JavaScript.

```
var receivedData = data.toString()
receivedData = JSON.parse(receivedData)
console.log(receivedData.canApprove)
```

This will work.